# element.style antes de GridView

Tags: css, gridview

Tengo un GridView dentro de una etiqueta `/table/tr/td/grdviuw`. Mi gridviuw tiene un css.

El problema es que cuando se renderiza, deja un espacio aparentemente después de la grilla y los botones que tengo debajo de la grilla se ven muy abajo, lejos de la grilla.

Cuando miro el código `html` en el explorador, veo que aparece antes de la grilla un div con un `height` fijo de `300px`, pero no se cómo ajustar ese `height` ya que ese div no está en mi código y el estilo de ese `div` aparece así:

```
element.style {    
    overflow: auto;
    height: 300px; //cuando quito esto desde el explorador, me queda perfecto
    width: 740px;
}
```

¿Cómo llego a ese estilo?:

Comment: Hola Carolina, bienvenida a Stack Overflow en Español. he editado tu pregunta. Tengo una inquietud: ¿puedes agregar una imagen de cómo está el GridView?, ¿si se llama GridView o "gridviuw"?. Edita tu pregunta con esta información. Si es posible, por favor, proporciona un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Saludos.

Comment: Hola Mauricio, muchas gracias. Adjunto las imagenes.

Comment: Carolina, una sugerencia es encerrar el GridView en un div, a ese div le pones una clase y le aplicas estilos.

Comment: :( ya lo intente y no funciona. Me coloca los botones justo debajo del div, pero la grilla se sale del div y quedan los botones por encimta de la grilla.

Answer (score 0):

Si ademas del div solo tienes el texto sin niguna etiqueta podrías poner simplemente

```
td div{
    display:none;
}
```

si no tienes solamente ese elemento, trata de agregarle una clase a ese td e igual jugar con la propiedad `display:none`